# The espace étalé as a scheme

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, schemes

On [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sheaf_(mathematics)#The_%C3%A9tal%C3%A9_space_of_a_sheaf), we find the following remark without reference: (here $\pi:E \to X$ is the espace étalé of a (pre)sheaf on $X$)

> It is possible to turn $E$ into a scheme and $\pi$  into a morphism of schemes in such a way that $\pi$  retains the same universal property, but $\pi$  is not in general an étale morphism because it is not quasi-finite. It is, however, formally étale.

So I'm wondering: what is the scheme structure on $E$? Do you we need some assumptions on the sheaf, such as quasicoherence?

Comment: It can be done without assumptions, for any sheaf of sets. The point is that you can pull back the structure sheaf along a local homeomorphism.